# c++ problemas con iterator - para vector<struct>

Tags: c++

tengo una estructura llamada procesos y con dicha estructura cree un vector, mi problema es que al recorrerlo me entrega múltiples errores.

```
void Robin_Round(){
    if(!Queue1.empty()){
        for(auto it = Queue1.begin(); it != Queue1.end(); it++){
            if(Tiempo_Actual>*it.tiempo_llegada){
                if(Tiempo_Actual + quantum>Tiempo_Actual + *it.rafaga - *it.tiempo_usado){
                    Tiempo_Actual = Tiempo_Actual + *it.rafaga - *it.tiempo_usado;
                    *it.tiempo_usado = *it.rafaga;
                    *it.tiempo_terminado = Tiempo_Actual;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

llevo ese estracto de codigo, pero al compilarlo me arroja el error

> C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\MLQ\main.cpp|113|error: 'it' does not name a type|
>   C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\MLQ\main.cpp|113|error: expected ';' before 'it'|
>   C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\MLQ\main.cpp|113|error: 'it' was not declared in this scope.

nose si influye pero estoy usando codeblocks 17.12

Comment: La única explicación que se me ocurre es que **no tengas activado** la versión C++11, o tu compilador no la soporte. ¿ Puedes comprobarlo ?

Comment: como podria comprobarlo?

Comment: El estándar no depende de la versión de codeblocks, que no es más que un IDE, sino del compilador. ¿Qué compilador y qué versión del mismo estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usando en operador flecha(cambiar *it. por it->) para acceder a los elementos del struct y claro compilando con el standar c++11:

```
void Robin_Round(){
    if(!Queue1.empty()){
        for(auto it = Queue1.begin(); it != Queue1.end(); it++){
            if(Tiempo_Actual>it->tiempo_llegada){
                if(Tiempo_Actual + quantum>Tiempo_Actual + it->rafaga - it->tiempo_usado){
                    Tiempo_Actual = Tiempo_Actual + it->rafaga - it->tiempo_usado;
                    it->tiempo_usado = it->rafaga;
                    it->tiempo_terminado = Tiempo_Actual;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo de qué manera tu propuesta puede solucionar el problema. ¿No es acaso equivalente `*it.` a `it->`?

Comment: Pues lo compile haciendo un ejemplo con un vector de structs(ya que no tengo el ejemplo completo) y así si compilo de la otra manera marcaba error

Comment: Para los apuntadores si es equivalente, para los iteradores it-> es equivalente a (*it).  , es decir usando los parentesis. saludos